# Titan's interior

Tags: interplanetary, cassini, titan

I'm reading an [article](http://phys.org/news/2015-10-saturn-moon-titan.html) and it says

> It's [sic] internal makeup is likely differentiated into several layers, with a 3,400-kilometre (2,100 mi) rocky center surrounded by layers composed of different forms of crystalized [sic] ice.

Does this mean the diameter of the "center" is 3,400 km? It's a bit ambiguous where this "center" ends. Anywhere I can find more details on Titan's interior?

Comment: What sort of details are you looking for?

Comment: Anything on the boundaries between the layers, temperature of Interior, how interior hints at possible volcanism, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different models for the internal structure of Titan, the wholly undifferentiated model, where the ice and rock are mixed together uniformly from surface to core and wholly differentiated model, where there is a separate rocky core surrounded by an ice shell.

The paper [Titan’s internal structure and the evolutionary consequences](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0032063311001401) by A.D. Fortes gives a detailed overview of interior of Titan. From the paper:

[image: Titan interior]

The interior looks something like this:

[image: Titan interior]

Source: nasa.gov

Comment: The data says the radius of the core + Ice layers is ~2,500km but it has no mention of the ocean unless one of the ices is considered to be the ocean layer?

Comment: @ThisPlayName Here's a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019103514001444) in *Icarus* covering the ocean.

Comment: It appears to me that the data are based on one structural model while the picture (which is missing Ice II and Ice V as well as showing the ocean) is based on another.  Perhaps phrasing should be added to clarify this difference?